# How to set the selector in MUI's sx property dynamically based on a variable?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a React component in which I want to hide all children after a certain number based on a dynamic variable. I'm using the sx property of Material UI to apply styles to the component.

This is the code I have:

```
<Container sx={{
    'div:nth-child(n+3)': {
        display: 'none'
    }
}}>
```

I want to make the n+3 part of the selector **dynamic**, based on a variable. Is there a way to achieve this in Material UI's sx property?

Here is what I've tried:

```
let n = 3;

<Container sx={{
    [`div:nth-child(n+${n})`]: {
        display: 'none'
    }
}}>
  <div>div 1</div>
  <div>div 2</div>
  <div>div 3</div>
  <div>div 4</div>
  <div>div 5</div>
 <Button onClick={handleChange()} >show more</Button>
</Container>
```

I also have a method that is called on a button click and supposed to change the value of n:

```
const handleChange = () => () => {
    n++;
};
```

I definitely land in the method and n is changed by it  (saw the console logs), but it does not change the number of divs displayed.

Can anyone help me figure out how to create a dynamic selector in MUI's sx property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you use a nested function for `handleChange`?

I made an example for it.
Please check it.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wafgu1?file=src%2FDynamicSX.js,src%2FApp.js

Comment: Thank you, this helped! My main problem was that the component wouldn't get re-rendered on function call, and that's where the React.useState was a game changer.

And yeah, the's no particular reason to use the nested function, thank you for the hint :)